# Vue - how to add reactive properties to objects in an array of objects?

Tags: vue.js

I have an array of objects coming from the backend. I need to add additional data onto each object, to send.

My data coming in looks like this:

```
let arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    city: 'Orlando',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    city: 'Miami',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    city: 'Portland',
  }
]
```

When the data comes loaded in through Vue, I need to have those properties be reactive. Meaning vue can see when those values change and call the appropiate lifecycle methods. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

```
let newArr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    city: 'Orlando',
    state: 'Fl',
    country: 'USA',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    city: 'Miami',
    state: 'Fl',
    country: 'USA',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    city: 'Portland',
    state: 'OR',
    country: 'USA',
  }
]
```

You can't just loop through and append properties to each object normally in vanillaJS, so how would you do this?

Answer (score 3):

The vue docs suggests to use `Object.assign` when appending properties to make them reactive

```
// instead of `Object.assign(this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 })`
this.someObject = Object.assign({}, this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 })
```

But, this is only if you have to append one object.

For a list of objects, this is how you would initialize the data

```
newArr = arr.map(item => {
  let newItem = Object.assign({}, item, {
    state: undefined,
    country: undefined,
  });
  return newItem;
});
```

Now all your objects properties in the array of objects are reactive

Answer (score 1):

Quite late but thought of providing the answer as it can be useful to someone else in the future:

If you would like to add an additional property to a certain object within an array of objects then you can use something like this:

```
var searchId = 1

const cityInfo = arr.find(ele => ele.id === searchId)
Vue.set(identifiersNode, 'state', "Karnataka")
Vue.set(identifiersNode, 'country', "India")
```

Answer (score 0):

Vue also intercepts calls to `Array.push`, so you may like this better:

```
arr.forEach(item => newArr.push(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

the *best approach* is to create a computed property.

**1. Without Store**

a Vue component like this:

```
data() {
 return {
  arr: []
 }
},
methods: {
 fetchArr() {
  // fetch array data
  this.arr = [...]
},
computed: {
 newArr() {
   return this.arr.map(item => {
    item.contry = '...'
    item.state = '...'
    return item
  })
 }
```

**2. With Store (Vuex)**

```
state() {
 return {
  arr: []
 }
}

mutations: {
  setArr(state, arr) {
   state.arr = arr
  }
}

actions: {
 fetchArr({commit}) {
 // api call
 commit('setArr', arr)
 }
}

getters: {
 newArr(state) {
  return state.arr.map(item => {
        item.contry = '...'
        item.state = '...'
        return item
      })
  }
}
```