# async await promise vue composition api console.log is correct but not in vue template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a multi-file input object "files" and I want to generate preview blob.  The previews object is correct, however doing `files.value.map` does not work. I want to attach the blob to the "files" object. What am I missing?

```
const files = ref([])
const previews = ref([])

const toBlob = async(file) => {
  const buffer = await file.arrayBuffer()
  const blob = new Blob([buffer])
  const srcBlob = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

  return srcBlob
}

watch(files, async() => {
  previews.value = await Promise.all(
    files.value.map((file) => toBlob(file))
  )

  await Promise.all(files.value.map(async(file) => {
     console.log(file)
     file.preview = await toBlob(file)
  }))
})

 return {
   files,
   previews
 }
```

This is blank in the vue template. console.log is correct however.

```html
<span v-for="file in files" :key="file">{{file.preview}}</span>
```

This is correct, showing the preview blob:

```html
<span v-for="preview in previews" :key="preview">{{preview}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

By passing an `async` function to `files.value.map`, you're getting an array of `Promise`s. You can't `await` this array directly, because you can only await a `Promise`.

Instead, you can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to turn an array of `Promise`s into a `Promise` of an array:

```
  await Promise.all(files.value.map(async(file) => {
    console.log(file)
    file.preview = await toBlob(file)
  }))
```

Comment: When I implemented your change, the file.preview shows up correctly in the console. However, it is not rendered in the vue template.

Comment: Not sure, I'm not that good with Vue yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the assignment of `file.preview` breaks the reactivity. You could try this in Vue3:

```js
let { preview } = toRefs(file)
preview.value = await toBlob(file)
```

References:

- https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-fundamentals.html#destructuring-reactive-state

Comment: toRefs would only work with a reactive object though right? I declared files as ref(), not reactive().

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56976631/vue-how-to-add-reactive-properties-to-objects-in-an-array-of-objects

Comment: I think that link answers my question

Comment: But I still can't make it to work properly :(

Comment: Can you check if your map function breaks reactivity? see from the docs: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/list.html#array-change-detection

Comment: And you probably need to assign the result of the map function to the appropriate variable, it doesn't mutate the original array.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you actually need to attach a `.preview` property to the `File` object, since you already store them in `previews[]`, so just remove that code:

```js
watch(files, async() => {
  previews.value = await Promise.all(
    files.value.map((file) => toBlob(file))
  )

  // xxx: remove
  //await Promise.all(files.value.map(async(file) => {
  //   console.log(file)
  //   file.preview = await toBlob(file)
  //}))
})
```

The object URLs would not be rendered as images with string interpolation (i.e., between curly bracket pairs). That is, `{{previewObjectUrl}}` would only render the URL as a string.

To render the blobs, the object URLs must be bound to an `<img>.src`:

```html
<img v-for="preview in previews" :key="preview" :src="preview">
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-image-preview?file=src/components/ImageInput.vue)